# Articles and elision in transcription

Tags: ortografia, fonologia

Consider the phrase:

#### "Como você tem passado o tempo livre?"

Translation: *How have you been spending your free time?*

There are a lot of phrases like this one, that have a definite article following a word that ends with that letter. I think quite a lot of native speakers would elide the article, so that "passado o tempo livre" sounds *identical* to "passado tempo livre".

In transcribing speech, is it natural for native lusófonos to transcribe spoken word **without including the definite article** from time to time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re quite right. All native speakers would pronounce one ***o*** only. That’s actually *the* standard pronunciation. But for this reason you don’t omit the ***o*** in writing. Let’s see a counterexample:

> Vou para Lisboa.

In careful, formal, speech you pronounce all the letters in *para*. In relaxed speech you can elide the first ***a*** (so, *p’ra*) or even the ***r*** as well (so, *p’a*). Fluent speakers will recognise these as three different versions of the word. Therefore if you want to transcribe speech accurately, you’ll write *para, p’ra*, or *p’a*, as the case may be. You use the apostrophe to indicate elided letters, but some people will simply write *pra*. But in *passado o tempo*, the definite article is fused with the final ***o*** of the previous word in standard pronunciation, so you never omit it in writing. It would look wrong, because in the mind of the speaker the definitive article is still there (thanks, tchrist). On the opposite: if someone, speaking unnaturally separating the words, pronounced the two ***o***, then you could write something like *passado―o―tempo*, to show that the person was separating the words.

This sort of thing happens with other adjacent vowels too, even if they are different. For instance when pronouncing *eu tenho a paciência* the final ***o*** of *tenho* disappears in fast speech (*eu tenh’a paciência*) or turns into the semivowel ***w*** of the English word *was* (so it will sound like *eu tênhua paciência*). And in *desde ontem* the final ***e*** of *deste* disappears in fast speech (*desd’ ontem*) or turns into the ***y*** semivowel of English *yet* (so sounding like *desdiontem*). But these are just the normal ways of speaking, so you always spell the words normally.

Comment: Is it truly elided in one's mind, or is this simply the customary fusion of adjacent, duplicated vowels? I'm guessing the latter.

Comment: @tchrist Fusion is the right term (maybe a should take it out of the parentheses). It's definitely not elided in one's mind: that's why it would be wrong to omit it in writing.

Answer (score 4):

Para responder primeiro à questão, se é natural durante transcrições omitir o artigo, a resposta é **não**; a questão não é tanto fonética, simplesmente, na maioria dos casos, apenas uma das alternativas, com ou sem artigo, é apropriada para o contexto, embora consigamos encontrar alguns exemplos em que ambas as formas são possíveis: «não tenho passado (o) tempo suficiente com ela» (de qualquer forma, neste caso, a existir, o artigo seria provavelmente pronunciado separamente).

Em segundo lugar, o fenómeno que apontas não se trata tanto de uma *elisão*, mas de uma *degeminação*, que é um tipo de *sândi vocálico*. Pode definir-se assim (Leda Bisol, [*A degeminação e elisão no sul do Brasil*](https://books.google.nl/books?id=V51ihhlkiGMC&lpg=PA231&ots=-rX7hzND4g&dq=degemina%C3%A7%C3%A3o&hl=pt-PT&pg=PA231#v=onepage&q&f=false), grafia original):

> A degeminação consiste na fusão de duas vogais idênticas e conseqüente encurtamento da vogal longa resultante, o que equivale a dizer que, como a elisão, perde um segmento.

Na expressão que indicas, *passado o tempo*, diria que ocorre de facto degeminação; não consigo imaginar uma frase em que não ocorra. Mas esse fenómeno não ocorre sempre, depende por exemplo do acento que as sílabas envolvidas tenham na frase. Para mais informação, vê o artigo [*O bloqueio do sândi vocálico em PB e em PE: evidências da frase fonológica*](http://www.seer.ufrgs.br/organon/article/download/31151/19330f), de Luciani Tenani.

Ainda assim, eu duvido que *passado tempo* e *passado o tempo* sejam pronunciados da mesma forma. Em *passado tempo*, a última sílaba de *passado* quase não é pronunciada, o que não é o caso em *passado o tempo*. Ouve [esta gravação](https://gist.github.com/cataphract/8ccd76d219f5eb336427/raw/716b04558ec40c373ff1e67b58466030adf70cac/passado_o_tempo.flac). Primeiro, tem uma frase com artigo, outra sem artigo e depois repetido na mesma ordem *passado (o)* até mesmo antes de começar o *t* de *tempo*.

Comment: I would mark you both as correct answers to the question if I could